# How to write a dict to a csv that have a list as its value and add a header for it

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary, header

I have a Dict that its value is a list, and I want to write it to a csv file which the key and all the items in a list (value) be in a separate cell in cvs file, this is how my Dict looks like:

my_dict = {'r1':[1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0], 'r2' : [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0]}

so I want my first cell in the first row in excel contains r1, and the all the items in a list in a separated cell respectively . and then I need to add a header like this (it can be a list like :
 `l = ['R','t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8']` [image: How the result in excel will look like]

EDITTED:

This is the code I tried:

```
with open (outputFileName, 'a') as outFile:
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    for r , t in enumerate(my_dict.items()):
        writer.writerow([r, *t])
```

but the result is the key in one cell, the value(whole list) in one cell. Tried nothing for the header yet

Comment: What have you tried till now, show that piece of code also, in the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was:-

The `enumerate()` function adds a counter to an iterable. So for each element in cursor , a tuple is produced with `(counter, element)` ; the for loop binds that to row_number and row , respectively. It's a builtin generator function, see 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate .

Here is the modified code.

```
import csv
my_dict = {'r1':[1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0], 'r2' : [0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0]}
outputFileName = 'test32.csv'
with open (outputFileName, 'a+') as outFile:
    writer = csv.writer(outFile)
    writer.writerow(['R','t1','t2','t3','t4','t5','t6','t7','t8'])
    for r , t in my_dict.items():
        writer.writerow([r, *t])
```

Output-

```
 R,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8
 r1,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0
 r2,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,0
```

Hope it helps.